# Show/Hide Elements jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and am after a little help with something!

Here is some of my code below:

---

**HTML**

```
<a id="showHideMenu">Discover...</a>
<a id="showHideContact">Contact</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showHideMenu").click(function(){
        $("#subMenuHere").toggle();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showHideContact").click(function(){
        $("#contactFormHere").toggle();
    });
});
```

---

At the moment if you select 'Discover...' the menu will show and if you select 'Contact' a contact form will show. However I would like it to work so if the menu is showing and you click 'Contact' the menu will hide and then the contact will show.

Let me know if you need anymore information!

Thanks

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SirCelsius/4h937wxk/)

Comment: what if contact is showing and again click contact?

Comment: You only have to include `$(document).ready(function(){` once - you can wrap all your code inside it. Alternatively if you put your JS at the end of your page (just before the `</body>` tag) you don't have to include it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't required multiple `document.ready`, use only one in single html page.

to show / hide menu and contact use below query.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showHideMenu").click(function(){
        $("#contactFormHere").hide();
        $("#subMenuHere").toggle();

    });

    $("#showHideContact").click(function(){
        $("#subMenuHere").hide();
        $("#contactFormHere").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Bhushan :) advice taken on board!

Comment: Multiple `$(document).ready()`s doesn't effect performance, only readability. So only use one per file for maintaining readabilty..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add .hide(); to the element you want to hide :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showHideMenu").click(function(){
        $("#contactFormHere").hide();
        $("#subMenuHere").toggle();

    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showHideContact").click(function(){
        $("#subMenuHere").hide();
        $("#contactFormHere").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear and you don't need to duplicate $(document).ready();

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showHideMenu").click(function(){
        $("#subMenuHere").toggle();
    });
    $("#showHideContact").click(function(){
        $("#contactFormHere").toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: The question isn't unclear - it's not perfect, but it's not exactly indecipherable.

Answer (score 0):

If it's important that one menu closes before the other opens, you'll need to use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showHideMenu").click(function(){
        if ($("#contactFormHere").is(":visible")) { // checks to see if the other element is visible
            $("#contactFormHere").toggle(400, function() {
                $("#subMenuHere").toggle();
            });
        } else {
            $("#subMenuHere").toggle();
        }
    });

    $("#showHideContact").click(function(){
        if ($("#subMenuHere").is(":visible")) {
            $("#subMenuHere").toggle(400, function() {
                $("#contactFormHere").toggle();
            });
        } else {
            $("#contactFormHere").toggle();
        }
    });
});
```